# Pandas move row based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to move every row that contains a specific character in a column to the bottom of the dataframe.....

```
    Index  Closer  Running
      0      4      AQ
      1      -      AQ
      2      -      AD
      3      2      AP
      4      9      AP
      5      5      AQ
```

I am trying to move every row in the Closer column that contains "-" to the bottom of the dataframe so my resultant dataframe looks like this, how do I go about doing this?

```
      Index  Closer  Running
      0      4        AQ
      1      2        AP
      2      9        AP
      3      5        AQ
      4      -        AQ
      5      -        AD
```

Comment: get the index of those rows where "-" is present. Use `loc` to index into two dataframes and simply concat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC, this is what you need.

```
m = df.Closer.str.isdigit()
df[m].append(df[~m]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output**

```
Index   Closer  Running
0   0   4   AQ
1   3   2   AP
2   4   9   AP
3   5   5   AQ
4   1   -   AQ
5   2   -   AD
```

Comment: better is `df[m].append(df[~m], ignore_index=True)`

Answer (score 5):

A one line solution is to filter DataFrame first, selecting rows with '-' and rows without it. Afterwards, you create a new DataFrame, which initially doesn't contain rows with '-', and second DF where only rows with '-' are stored. Then you concat them together.

```
d = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Closer':[4,'-','-',2,9,5],'Running':'AQ','AQ','AD','AP','AP','AQ']})
d = pd.concat([d[d.Closer!='-'],d[d.Closer=='-']])
d
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a new dataframe, to filter on the condition then concatenate the two dataframe.

e.g. assuming your data in `df`

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1 = df1.append(df[df["Closer"] != "-"])
df1 = df1.append(df[df["Closer"] == "-"])
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
df.loc[(~df.Closer.str.isdigit()).sort_values(kind='mergesort').index]
Out[24]: 
   Index Closer Running
0      0      4      AQ
3      3      2      AP
4      4      9      AP
5      5      5      AQ
1      1      -      AQ
2      2      -      AD
```

Comment: Note that I don't think this is guaranteed to preserve the order, because the default sort method IIUC is a non-stable quicksort.  You'd have to specify `kind='mergesort'` to guarantee the same results as the other approaches.