# Sort only parts of pandas Dataframe based on column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a followup question to the question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72783629/move-pandas-row-to-end-based-on-condition).

My pandas dataframe consists of several columns, the first column has string values, the others have floats. It looks something like this:

```
Superheros        hourly rate
Spiderman (Nr 1)   12.9
Batman (Nr 4)      93.7
Joker              23.6
Iron Man (Nr 2)    49.3
Hulk               32.5
Captain America    24.9
Wonderwoman (Nr 3) 65.8
```

In general the dataframe should be sorted based on the column of hourly rate, but all superheros with a number should be located at the bottom of the dataframe. The resulting dataframe should look like this

```
Superheros        hourly rate
Hulk               32.5
Captain America    24.9
Joker              23.6
Batman (Nr 4)      93.7
Wonderwoman (Nr 3) 65.8
Iron Man (Nr 2)    49.3
Spiderman (Nr 1)   12.9
```

In my question from before I didn't have the condition of sorting by the second column, and the suggested solution led to this code snipplet:

```
df['Superheros'] = df['Superheros'].str.replace(r'\bim\s+(Nr\s*\d+)', r'(\1)', regex=True)
df = df.replace(np.nan, '-')
s = pd.to_numeric(df['Superheros'].str.extract('\(VG (\d+)\)', expand=False))
idx = s.sort_values(na_position='first').index
df = df.loc[idx]
```

based on the same logic it was suggested to use:

```
sorter = lambda s: pd.to_numeric(s.str.extract('\(Nr (\d+)\)', expand=False))

out = df.sort_values(by='Superheros', key=sorter, na_position='first')
```

So I thought I could simply change by='Superheros' to by='hourly rate', but this does not work (I think I understand why). Unfortunately I don't have any other idea on how else to do this, besides maybe splitting the dataframe in two parts, sorting them seperatly and then merging them back together. Is there a nicer pythonic way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What I would likely do is make a new column with the Nr in it (give NaN to ones without), then just sort by two columns. Eg. `df.sort_values(['Fee', 'Duration'], ascending = [False, True])`. You could delete the column after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative solution, you can use [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-values) twice, the second one with a `key` parameter:

```
res = (df.sort_values(by="hourly rate", ascending=False)
       .sort_values(by=["Superheros"], key=lambda x: x.str.contains(pat=r"\d", regex=True)))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
           Superheros  hourly rate
4                Hulk         32.5
5     Captain America         24.9
2               Joker         23.6
1       Batman (Nr 4)         93.7
6  Wonderwoman (Nr 3)         65.8
3     Iron Man (Nr 2)         49.3
0    Spiderman (Nr 1)         12.9
```

**Note on performance**

Sometimes sorting twice can be faster, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69468552/efficiency-of-sorting-by-multiple-keys-in-python). Additionally for an out-sample of your original df (see [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html#pandas-dataframe-sample)):

```
df = df.sample(1000, replace=True)  # len(df) is 1000
```

I get the following timings:

```
%timeit df.sort_values(by="hourly rate", ascending=False).sort_values(by=["Superheros"], key=lambda x: x.str.contains(pat=r"\d", regex=True))
781 µs ± 2.24 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
%timeit df.assign(bottom=df['Superheros'].str.contains('\d\)')).sort_values(by=['bottom', 'hourly rate'], ascending=[True, False]).drop(columns='bottom')
1.36 ms ± 7.34 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly the typ of solution I was looking for! Just had to change the pat expression to \(Nr (\d+)\), and now it works :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a temporary column to sort the Superheros with numbers:

```
(df
 .assign(bottom=df['Superheros'].str.contains('\d\)'))
 .sort_values(by=['bottom', 'hourly rate'], ascending=[True, False])
 .drop(columns='bottom')
)
```

output:

```
           Superheros  hourly rate
4                Hulk         32.5
5     Captain America         24.9
2               Joker         23.6
1       Batman (Nr 4)         93.7
6  Wonderwoman (Nr 3)         65.8
3     Iron Man (Nr 2)         49.3
0    Spiderman (Nr 1)         12.9
```

intermediate (without dropping the 'bottom' column):

`True` (=1) is sorted after `False` (=0).

```
           Superheros  hourly rate  bottom
4                Hulk         32.5   False
5     Captain America         24.9   False
2               Joker         23.6   False
1       Batman (Nr 4)         93.7    True
6  Wonderwoman (Nr 3)         65.8    True
3     Iron Man (Nr 2)         49.3    True
0    Spiderman (Nr 1)         12.9    True
```